# HTML5 Validation Errors: body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open AND Stray end tag head

Tags: html, validation, error-handling

It's my first post here, hope to do it the right way :)

I'm trying to undestrand and resolve two errors that https://validator.w3.org/ tells me: "Body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open" and "Stray end tag head". I checked the code various times and can't find where I have the second  tag. I read that those errors can occur when something inappropriate is placed inside  but can't figure out what exactly goes wrong. Is the  with the rel="stylesheets" a problem? I can't remove that to check because it's a code that add translation tool to the website. The website was build on Webflow.

The website: https://www.rinnovision.com/ (The code is too big to paste it here)
Thank you!

I tried to visully expect the code, to google and read Stackoverflow and Webflow forums. But didn't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I reallly don't know what to add to describe better an issue. If someone can help and tell me, what can I add to my explanation...